# Simple count of number of records in ManyToMany table

Tags: django, many-to-many, django-queryset

```
class Author(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   age = models.IntegerField()
   friends = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True)

class Publisher(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
   num_awards = models.IntegerField()

class Book(models.Model):
   isbn = models.CharField(max_length=9)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
   pages = models.IntegerField()
   price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
   rating = models.FloatField()
   authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
   publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher)
   pubdate = models.DateField()

class Store(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
   books = models.ManyToManyField(Book)
```

I think I'm missing something really obvious but how do I get a count for the number of records created in this many-to-many table `authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check out [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/queries/#many-to-many-relationships), it's pretty simple:

```
b = Book.objects.all()[0]
b.authors.count()
```

**Update:**

The original question was asking for a list of all of the Authors in the database, not looking for a list of authors per book.

To get a list of all of the authors in the database:

```
Author.objects.count() ## Returns an integer.
```

Comment: I promise you I was searching like mad. All the examples give a filtered query. For some reason, the `[0]` part doesn't show up anywhere even in the link you embedded.

Comment: The `[0]` simply selects the first `Book` in the queryset.  It is the same as saying:  `Book.objects.get(pk=1)` (assuming the first `Book` has the primary key of `1`).

Comment: So If I do `Book.objects.get(pk=1)`, I will get the same result at `b = Book.objects.all()[0]` in my count?

Comment: I don't understand why I need to select the first book in order to do a count on the authors field which may contain many other books?

Comment: Yes.  It is the exact same as working with a list.  I'm just pulling the first item off of that list for brevity.

Comment: Hey Jack, thanks for replying and not going RTFM. Think it's just late and my brain is shutting down. Really wanted to solve this before I hit the shack. Will re-visit the docs tomorrow.

Comment: If you want to get the list of all authors in the system, you should re-word your question.  It sounds as though you want the count of authors on a single result.

Comment: Thats what I want, a simple count of all the authors. But why is it I need to create a single object to do the count?

Comment: @Nai let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1328/discussion-between-jack-m-and-nai)

Comment: Honestly, it sounds like @super9 wants the number of entries in the "invisible" linking table, like the number of rows you would get from an SQL left join of `select * from books join books_authors on books.id == books_authors.book_id join authors on books_authors.author_id == authors.id`.  That's like what *I* want anyway, and I don't think it's possible in django, at least not in a way that lets you paginate a template where every combo is a separate row...